# Any ID I could reference in sections

Tags: entries, sections, channels, id

I created a section for appointment record (channel type). Each appointment record has different fields, i.e. customer name, phone#, address, etc... I would like to set a unique appointment_record_id (Numeric, i.e. 234) for each record.  Is there any way to create it?

Comment: Not 100% sure I'm following... is `appointment_record_id` a custom field?  If so, what type of field is it?  Do you want it to be auto-populated on a new entry or when an entry is saved?

Comment: @BradBell yes, `appointment_record_id` is a custom field. I set that field is `Number`. I want auto-populated on a new entry.

Answer (score 1):

If you were to do this on entry save, it'd be much easier/cleaner.

You'd write a [simple plugin](https://pluginfactory.io) that listened to the [`onBeforeSaveEntry`](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/events-reference#entries-onBeforeSaveEntry) event.

The plugin would check the `isNewEntry` param to make this this is a new entry and not an existing one.

If it's new, you could generate a random numeric value with [mt_rand](http://php.net/mt_rand), assign it to your custom field and left the request continue so Craft can save it to the entry.

A string field for the unique identifier would be better though, since mt_rand will not always produce unique numbers (for unique numbers you'd need to keep a separate database table and obtain id's within a transaction). If you'd use strings you could use [uniqid('', true)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) if you deploy on a single server, or better use a [uuid/guid](http://codeaid.net/php/generate-a-random-guid).

If you didn't do it on save, but wanted to be auto-populated when someone clicked "New Entry", you'd have to do something much more hacky like have [JS loaded](https://github.com/lindseydiloreto/craft-cpjs) load, try to target the field in the particular section with JavaScript and inject the random number into the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Brad, I created a plugin with `appointment_record_id` (PK with auto increment), `customer_id` and `timestamp` table. I insert a record when system creates Appointment Record, and then I reference the `appointment_record_id` as my id.